# Milliseconds automatically added to java.util.Date / Joda DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to create a java.util.Date object without the milliseconds part. eg: `2018-03-19T15:04:23+00:00`. This is the code I have:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
Date d = new Date();
String strFromD = sf.format(d);
Date dFromStr = sf.parse(strFromD);
```

When I debug this and inspect the variables, I see this:
[image]

The String which I get by formatting the date does not have any milliseconds. However, when I create a date back from the String, it has the milliseconds part.

I tried the same using Joda DateTime as well:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String strFromDt = dateFormatter.print(dt);
DateTime dtFromStr = dateFormatter.parseDateTime(strFromDt);
System.out.println("DT : "+dt);
System.out.println("String from DT : "+strFromDt);
System.out.println("DT from String : "+dtFromStr);
```

And this is the output:

```
DT : 2018-03-22T09:30:22.996-07:00
String from DT : 2018-03-22T09:30:22-07:00
DT from String : 2018-03-22T09:30:22.000-07:00
```

Again, when I try to get the DateTime from the String, it adds the milliseconds back.

Am I missing something here? Do I need to use 2 different formatters or something?

Comment: What do you mean _without the milliseconds_? A `Date` represents a timestamp with millisecond precision. Do you just not want them shown in a `String` created from that date?

Comment: "However, when I create a date back from the String, it has the milliseconds part." That's not what your screenshot shows - `dFromStr` appears to be "on the second" (i.e. millisecond-of-second is 0). Isn't that what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This is where I'm confused. I'm actually using a 3rd party SDK which accepts a java.util.Date as a parameter to one of the methods. And the documentation says it should be in `2018-03-19T15:04:23+00:00` format. So I'm not exactly clear as to how I would achieve this. I keep getting an invalid format exception from the SDK.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to remove the milliseconds part completely.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by that. A `Date` *is* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, internally. The closest to "removing milliseconds" you can get is "making sure that millisecond-of-second is 0". If you're trying to get a string representation without milliseconds, that's *entirely different*. Please clarify.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are right. Like I said in my comment above, I keep getting an exception from the SDK that I'm using. That's why I wanted to see if I'm missing something.

Comment: "The SDK" is pretty vague (we've no idea which SDK you mean) but if it's claiming that it requires a particular *text format* while accepting a `java.util.Date` then that's a non-sequitur. It's like having an `int` parameter and saying "it has to be in hex".

Comment: @drunkenfist please provide exception. As others said, there seems to be a misunderstanding around Date, millis and SDK requirement.

Comment: To fully understand your problem, please provide the code where you pass the "date" to the SDK.

Comment: You may want to quote that documentation requiring a `java.util.Date` in a specific format so we may help you decipher.

Answer (score 1):

If your SDK expects a `java.util.Date`, there's no point talking about a format, because [dates don't have a format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

The `Date` class represents one numerical value: the number of milliseconds since [Unix Epoch (*Jan 1<sup>st</sup> 1970, at midnight, in UTC*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). To make a *date without the milliseconds*, you could truncate this milliseconds value:

```
Date d = new Date();
// truncate the number of milliseconds since epoch (eliminate milliseconds precision)
long secs = d.getTime() / 1000;
// create new Date with truncated value
d = new Date(secs * 1000);
```

In Joda-Time, it's a little bit simpler:

```
// set milliseconds to zero
DateTime dt = new DateTime().withMillisOfSecond(0);
// convert to java.util.Date
Date date = dt.toDate();
```

If your SDK expects a `String`, though, then it makes sense talking about formats. A date can be represented (aka "transformed in text") in many different ways:

- 2018-03-22T09:30:22-07:00
- March 22<sup>nd</sup> 2018, 9:30:22 AM
- 22/03/2018 09:30:22.000
- and so on...

Objects like `java.util.Date` and Joda's `DateTime` **don't** have a format. They just hold **values** (usually, numerical values), so if your SDK expects one of those objects, just pass them and don't worry about it.

If the SDK expects a `String` in a specific format (a **text representing a date**), then you should transform your date objects to that format.

And if this format doesn't allow milliseconds, so be it:

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
String dateFormattedAsString = sdf.format(d);
```

With Joda-Time:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
String dateFormattedAsString = fmt.print(dt);
```

Those will not change the date's values, but the strings won't have the milliseconds printed.